responsibility of mapper and segregation of DTO , Pojo and Entity in a spring boot application following clean architecture
I have a spring boot crud application.
taking a single entity 'User' for example
I have distributed the application in three layers by three packages

entity (UserEntity , UserRepository)
infrastructure (UserDto , RestUserController)
useCases (UserPpojo, CRUD useCases as services)

I try to keep the three layer completely independent as possible

UserDto is sent and received through out the controller methods
UserPojo is sent and received throughout the services (usecases)
UserEntity is sent and received throughout the services (usecases)

I have two mappers

entityToPojo
dtoToPojo

in my limited knowledge , I think the segregation is enough to maintain clean architecture
I have two concern/dilemma which I cant rectify

which layers do the mappers belong
because each layer deals in only one data currency (DTO , Pojo, Entity) , it has to be mapped before or after passing to the different layer , so the responsibility of mapping should stick to the same layer or the other layer

for example ,
I have a Controller method to add user
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> add(UserDto userDto) {
        UserPojo userPojo = userPojoToDtoMappers.toPojo(userDto);
        userPojo = createUserUseCase.execute(userPojo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userPojoToDtoMappers.toDto(userPojo));
    }

and a service method to be called from the controller
public UserPojo execute(UserPojo userPojo) {
        return userPojoGateway.add(userPojo);
    }

In My example , the burden of mapping is kept with the calling layer (controller), but this seems to be breaking the clean architecture as the POJO information has to be shared with both controller and service layer
Kindly suggest , which layer should have the mappers , and should the caller or receiver hold the burden of mapping

It's not about the caller and receiver method. Here, we are trying to implement layered architecture. In a layered architecture, you want to have a certain abstraction between your layers.

The controller should provide some abstraction. In the controller, you should place logic related to the incoming request and the final response of your API
All the mappings, and business logic should happen in the Service Layer.
Finally DAO layer should have the mapping of entities and db operations.

I hope it helped you understand the concept.
